Enforcing HTTP/1.1 and up on apache
Seeing that most people use HTTP/2.0 or HTTP/3, I thought of making changes to apache so it refuses connections to those using HTTP/1.0 or lower.
Before suggesting mod_rewrite, I want to apply settings at a much deeper level, preferably via a custom module so less processing time is wasted on robots that continue to connect to the server via HTTP/1.0.
I looked at the HttpProtocolOptions Directive but their documentation suggests that I could enforce HTTP/1.0 and up, but I need to block HTTP/1.0 because it doesn't support keep-alives.
So I did make my own module and I tried applying it using SetHandler directive but it fights with PHP because I also have an AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php. By fighting, I mean I can only have the PHP module running or my module running. I'd rather have it where my module always runs first regardless of the incoming request then the php module run after if a php file is called.
So what's the best way I should tackle this? The end goal is to give an error when someone connects to any webpage on the server using HTTP/0.9 (or lower) or HTTP/1.0 protocols, but those using HTTP/1.1 and higher can access the pages.

Why bother with a custom module?
Just create a default Virtualhost and that will catch HTTP/1.0 (and I expect HTTP/0.9 - but I've not noticed any of those) and return whatever error you want - and then specify a virtualhost/virtualhosts for your actual hosts - ie take advantage of the fact that HTTP/1.1 supports name based virtual hosting but 1.0 and earlier doesn't.

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44282207/how-to-disable-http-1-0-protocol-in-apache for how to use a rewrite engine to check the SERVER_PROTOCOL variable to handle redirection.
